# Northwind database JOIN QUERY between three tables (many to many)

Tags: sql, linq, join, model-view-controller

I have three tables of **Northwind database** ,

> Employee (field:employeeID) 1-*
>
> Order (field:Orderid,customerid,employeeid)*-1
>
> Customer (field:customerID) .

So 1 `Employee` has many `Orders` and 1 `Customer` have many `orders` , so it is `[Employee 1*Order *1 Customer ]` relationship , with an order table in the middle. So how do i extract and display in a mvc view ALL `EMPLOYEES` THAT HAVE `CUSTOMERS` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, we assume the every Order has a Customer, so if an Employee has an Order, he must also have a Customer.  So, we can forget about the Customer Table.  We really just want to know, Which Employees have Orders.  For that, we look at the Orders and gather a list of Employees that own them:

```
  (from o in Orders
  select o.Employee).Distinct()
```

Comment: `So this is a part of how view looks like:

@model Northwind.Employees
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Me";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/MasterDetailsLayoutPage.cshtml";
}
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EmployeeID)
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.EmployeeID)
........AND SOME OTHER EMPLOYEES FIELD....
THEN HERE display a table:
foreach(item in Model.Customers)
.....display a table of customers for this employee(example EMPLOYEEID:5 ).
This is the controller :
dbNorthwindEntities db = new dbNorthwindEntities(); 

/* public ActionResult Details()
{
//query comes here
return View(); 
}*/`